# Am unable to extract file that was achieved as Artifact to be used in a devops released pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O1LN.png)
i have configure a devops pipeline to use terraform, i have setup branch policies so that code can only be merged into main with Pull Request. the continuous Deployment pipeline works as it outputs the file as a artifact. The release pipeline is suppose to download the artifact from the destination folder and consume in the release pipeline, The error message i get is file can not be extracted because it can not be accessed:

##[error]Specified archive: /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform Plan/8-tfplan/8-tfplan.tgz can not be extracted because it can not be accessed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform Plan/8-tfplan/8-tfplan.tgz'
    at Object.statSync (node:fs:1551:3)

Can anyone advice how to troubleshoot this suppose you ran into this or what the solution can be looking at the attached error message below , ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6w4A.png)

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E7sm.png)

Comment: Sound like the file don't exists. Maybe case issue.

Comment: just curious why it says the artifact was created , it was able to download the artifact but cannot extract it

Comment: What is the artifact file format?

Comment: its a Zip file using .tgz to compress it